Building a custom keyboard with Cherry green switches, RGB backlit, trying to find keycaps / switches that do not bleed light
I am building a custom keyboard.  102 key, all metal (aluminum). I like the feel of Cherry MX Green 80 Clicky) switches but unsure if they're compatible with an RGB backlight. The aluminum chassis I want to use has rgb lighting built in.
I am trying to find keycaps (and, perhaps, different switches?) that do NOT bleed any light.  I want the letter or symbol ONLY to glow with light - not underneath the switch or around the switch.  THROUGH the keycap only.  And the keycap itself should not glow - ONLY the letter or symbol it is representing.
There are so many keyboards these days that are rgb backlit, but the light bleeds out all around the switch and very little, if any actually makes it through to illuminate the letter or symbol.  Kind of defeats the purpose (in my book) while typing in a darkened room.
I am merely researching to find a keycap (any), Cherry green (or something similar) keyboard switch, 102+ key set that does NOT bleed light except THROUGH the keycap to illuminate the curves, lines and vertices of the letter, number or symbol itself.
